# Adobe AIR: Controls flipped (mirrored) in certain build environments

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4

I'm having an issue where certain controls are flipped, depending on the machine that I'm building my project on. On my development machine, when I build it, everything is okay. However, when I build it on our build server, some things are flipped. It seems to be things that are on a higher layer - for instance, options in the select control (see first image below), alerts/overlays (see second image below), etc. It's not just the text, either - the entire content is flipped, images and all.

[image]

[image]

I have verified that the code is exactly the same in both instances, so it must have something to do with settings or the flex SDK version. On my development machine, the Flex SDK version is 4.0.0.14159, and on the build server, the Flex SDK version is 4.1.0.16076. I can downgrade the SDK on the build server if needed - but could it really be an issue with the SDK? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Having same issue with an MX application that is being compiled against 4.1.0.16076.  For anyone else interested in this issue, the oa had a little better luck posting on the Adobe forums -- http://forums.adobe.com/message/3070051.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this will be fixed in the 4.5 SDK--see [SDK-26473](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-26473) for workarounds.

I was able to fix the mirroring by turning off Flex 3 Compatibility Mode in the Flex compiler settings (if using mxmlc, `-compatibility-version=4.0`).

Answer (score 0):

Your build machine must be set to a locale which uses right-to-left text, such as Hebrew or Arabic keyboard setting.

Comment: I thought of this, but the images are flipped too - that can't be right, can it? I'll look into it, though... thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Oops - hadn't read all of dpstone's answer before I posted my comment to the question.

The answer to this problem is in the bug he linked to.  You need to explicitly set the layout direction.  You can do this in one of two ways.

**1)** in a .css file that you import into your main application file:

```
global
{
    layoutDirection: "ltr";
}
```

OR

**2)** you can set it in a `<style>` tag in your main application file.

```
<mx:Style>
    global
    {
        layoutDirection: "ltr";
    }
</mx:Style>
```