# Adobe Flex Title Window showing mirror image of itself

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4

I have a flex 3 application with  2 titlewindows. When I compile it with the flex 4.1 sdk in flash builder, the titlewindows show up as mirror images of themselves with all text invisible (i.e alpha = 0).

I don't know where to begin looking for a solution. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: It would help us help you if you could post some of your code.

Comment: @Jason I'm unable to recreate the problem in a simple sample.

Comment: Do you get any warnings when you compile it in Flash Builder? Do you have the 'Use Flex 3 Compatibility' box checked in your project properties?

Comment: Nope to compile warnings and yes to compatibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've read about this happening before, sounds like it's a known issue.  See the following for more info and a potential workaround: [Adobe AIR: Controls flipped (mirrored) in certain build environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516527/adobe-air-controls-flipped-mirrored-in-certain-build-environments)

Comment: Thanks Wade the link led me to a workaround available here : http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-26473?focusedCommentId=366510&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#action_366510                             Adding the following to my only css file 
   global{ 
     layoutDirection: "ltr"; 
    } 
solved the problem.